# How to go about searching a length-delimited dictionary

Tags: java, file-io

I'm creating a word game in Java for practice. I've got a txt file containing all the four-letter words in the English language. They are length-delimited, i.e. every 4th character starting from the 1st is the first letter of a word.

What is a good way to go about checking to see if a word exists in the dictionary?

Comment: are they ordered? Then binary search. Otherwise they need to be ordered first. If you can read it into memory then it's even easier.

Comment: They're alphabetically ordered. The file is only 15KB, so it can be copied into memory. I'd really like some code examples to see how other people might go about this, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file into a `TreeSet` then use the `contains` method. For a `Set` contains runs in constant time. I have added a `.toUpperCase()` conversion so that there are no case related issues, this can easily be a `.toLowerCase()` also.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final TreeSet<String> strings = new TreeSet<>();
    try (final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
           System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/words.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
        final char[] buffer = new char[4];
        int numRead = -1;
        while ((numRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            strings.add(new String(buffer, 0, numRead).toUpperCase());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(strings.contains("FLIP"));
    System.out.println(strings.contains("JUMP"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually a _lot_ easier than I expected it to be.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Java, would you mind expounding a little bit on each line so I can follow what's happening?

Comment: Also, this isn't working for me. `strings.contains()` returns `false` for any string.

Comment: Just kidding. It works. My text file was encoded in UTF-8 instead of ANSI. Switched that, now it works.